# How to link shared object in cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake

How can I link shared object to my own code in cmake ?
I'd like to link OpenCV, I mean libopencv_***.so.3.1 or something like that to my own software package.

In that case, I believe the following lines are the answer of this question.

```
...
find_package(OpenCV 3.1)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
...
target_link_libraries(my_node ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

But, here's this problem.
I've installed OpenCV 2.4.8 under /usr/include and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu before, and now I'd like to use OpenCV 3.1.0 installed in local directory "~/Libs/opencv" from code.
So when compiling the codes, OpenCV 2.4.8 takes priority and is used.

In this case, how should I describe CMakeLists.txt ?
Currently I'm writing as the follow.

```
...
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${HOME}/Libs/opencv)
include(${HOME}/Libs/opencv/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake)
find_package(OpenCV 3.1)
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS ${HOME}/Libs/opencv/include)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS)
set(OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS ${HOME}/Libs/opencv/lib)
link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
...
```

The above CMakeLists.txt kind of helped me.
If executable file is copied to the same directory where libopencv_***.so.3.1 is, the above CMakeLists.txt works.
Otherwise, "make" fails.
But I'd like to make it independent on the directory which contains executable file.

How should I do for this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4 upvotes within an hour…?

Comment: You have to adjust the order of libraries with BEFORE and AFTER.

Comment: Look at this: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling it could help

Comment: Thanks ! It worked !
I added
`set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)`
`set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)`
`set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "<path-to-opencv-lib-directory>")`
`set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)`
to cmake file.

Answer (score 1):

See cmake's doc of `find_library`.
Some predefined paths are used to search for libs. (Platform dependent). It is possible to disable this by options.
Try
`find_package(OpenCV 3.1 PATHS ~/Libs/opencv NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Actually this was not enough, but I could solve the problem as I mentioned above.